# R script for extracting rows from several text files

Tags: r, regression, information-extraction

I have 900 text files in my directory as seen in the following figure below

[image]

each file consists of data in the following format

```
667869 667869.000000 
580083 580083.000000 
316133 316133.000000 
11065 11065.000000
```

I would like to extract fourth row from each text file and store the values in an array, any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a StackOverflow question, similar to 
[Importing multiple .csv files into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/importing-multiple-csv-files-into-r)

You can try something like:

> setwd("/path/to/files")
>
> files <- list.files(path = getwd(), recursive = FALSE)
>
> head(files)
>
> myfiles = lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(file = x, header = TRUE))
>
> mydata = lapply(myfiles, FUN = function(df){df[4,]})
>      str(mydata)
>
> do.call(rbind, mydata)

Answer (score 0):

A lazy answer is:

```
array <- c()  
for (file in dir()) {  
  row4 <- read.table(file,
                     header = FALSE,
                     row.names = NULL,
                     skip = 3,  # Skip the 1st 3 rows
                     nrows = 1,  # Read only the next row after skipping the 1st 3 rows
                     sep = "\t")  # change the separator if it is not "\t"  
  array <- cbind(array, row4)
}
```

You can further keep the name of the files

```
colnames(array) <- dir()
```

Comment: I would like  to read multiple files with pattern regional_vol_*.txt, so when i use filename regional_vol_*.txt its throwing an error